# Equivalent of Ruby "redo" in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ruby, loops, for-loop

Is there an equivalent method of performing the job of `redo` in C#? i.e. going back to the top of the loop and re-execute without checking conditions or increasing the loop counter. Thanks.

Comment: @Saju `continue` will still increase the loop counter..

Comment: I know that. What I meant is let OP try with `continue`. This was not an answer just a comment :)

Comment: Unfortunately I need the counter to remain the same as while I'm iterating I want to handle a whole collection not just those who don't throw an exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    do
    {
        DoYourStuff();
    } while (ShouldWeDoThatAgain());
}
```

`Do...while` is like a standard `while` loop, except instead of checking its conditional before each iteration, it checks after. That way, the code inside the loop will always execute at least once. Stick that inside a `for` or `foreach` loop, and that should get you the behavior your want. This is a bit simpler than Simon's answer, as it doesn't require an extra variable, doesn't use `continue`, and doesn't mess with the loop counter at all.

Answer (score 5):

Why not simply:

Although `goto` is not really everyone's favourite, it's quite readable in this case...

```
for(...)
{
redo:

   //...

   if (...)
      goto redo;




}
```

Comment: @TylerLong: That's what's most important, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

No. The closest you'll get is something like this:

```
bool redoCalled = false:

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (redoCalled) {
        i--;
        redoCalled = false;
    }

    // other stuff here

    if (redoWanted) {
        redoCalled = true;
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if redoCalled is set in the last cycle. You need to decrement i at the end of the  loop.